# Reading cells in Excel file which contains dates, if date is > 300 days past, send email notification

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I am storing information with dates and associated with them in an Excel file on Sharepoint.  When the current date gets to 1 year (365 calendar days) since the date in the cell, I want to automatically generate an email, and send it to the user in a cell on the same line.

For example, when the `foo` line-item's date is exactly 365 days past the current date, I'd like to automate the sending of an email to the address on the same line.

| item | email | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo | a@mail.net | 05/10/22 |

Are there any options native to Sharepoint that will do this?  If not, what add-ons, apps or approaches could I accomplish this with?

If not email, are there any MS Teams integrations that exist that could do this?

Comment: I want to confirm something with you. Your form information is stored in an excel file, and then this excel file is uploaded to the sharepoint library?

Comment: Yes, that is correct